# How to get validation error keys in Sequel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, sequel

There is a rails application with Sequel instead of ActiveRecord.

After validation of record with invalid params, I got this:

```
message = Message.new(some_bad_params)
message.errors
=> {
    :subject=>["is not present", "is too short or too long"],
    :notifications=>["is not present"]
   }
```

In this case, in API response I need to somehow send error keys of this record.

**Not error messages** because API client is another rails application with different languages and localizations.

In ActiveRecord is possible just call ["details" method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors-errors-details) like `record.errors.details` and receives [keys](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation)

But in Sequel is does not work. Because it's not implemented =)

Could you kindly suggest the best way how to get the keys of validation error messages?

I checked [validation_helpers.rb](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/plugins/validation_helpers.rb) Sequel's plugin, but there is a suggestion only about the redefining of error messages. But what about error keys?

Comment: "Is there some gem that already solves this problem?" Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't recommend off-site resources. Instead, you have to do the research and find something that seems appropriate to your use, then try it, then, if you run into a problem, ask a specific question about the problem you encounter. Currently your question is way ahead of that.

Comment: You might want to check with the Sequel IRC or Group Forum. The author and other power-users hang out there. See "[Resources](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Resources)" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, if you want to get the keys then this is the case: `message.errors.keys`

```
message = Message.new(some_bad_params)
message.errors
# get keys
=> {
  :subject=>["is not present", "is too short or too long"],
  :notifications=>["is not present"]
}
message.errors.keys
=> [:subject, :notifications]
```